# How to find the smallest value of element in matrix with size (9,2,2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Supposing I have a matrix A with the np.shape(A) = (9,2,2).
Then, I would like to find the smallest element value for the inner matrix (2,2) of total 9 outer matrix. Let's call it B.
Could anyone let me know what is the numpy code, please?
Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[[24, 73],
             [35, 67]],

            [[35, 68],
            [21,  5]],

            [[29, 69],
            [60, 46]],

            [[98, 25],
            [50, 92]],

            [[63, 27],
            [55, 28]],

            [[60, 89],
            [61, 66]],

            [[87, 38],
            [44, 33]],

            [[64, 76],
            [76, 70]],

            [[90, 91],
            [71, 58]]])

np.shape(A)
```

**Expected Result**

```
B = [24,5,29,25,27,60,38,64,58]

np.shape(B) = (9,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Solution`

```py
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[[24, 73],
             [35, 67]],

            [[35, 68],
            [21,  5]],

            [[29, 69],
            [60, 46]],

            [[98, 25],
            [50, 92]],

            [[63, 27],
            [55, 28]],

            [[60, 89],
            [61, 66]],

            [[87, 38],
            [44, 33]],

            [[64, 76],
            [76, 70]],

            [[90, 91],
            [71, 58]]])

B1 = A.min(axis=(1, 2))
B2 = np.min(A, axis=(1, 2))

print("B1 =", B1)
print("B2 =", B2)
print("np.shape(B1) =", np.shape(B1))
```

Find minimum value with 2 menthods

## 1.

```py
B1 = A.min(axis=(1, 2))
```

## 2.

```py
B2 = np.min(A, axis=(1, 2))
```

Find shape of array in numpy

```py
shape = np.shape(B1)
```

### `Output`

```
B1 = [24  5 29 25 27 60 33 64 58]
B2 = [24  5 29 25 27 60 33 64 58]
np.shape(B1) = (9,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) aggregating on the last two axes:

```
A.min((1, 2))
```

Alternatively, if you want a generic code to handle any number of dimensions, `reshape` then aggregate the `min` on the last dimension:

```
A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1).min(-1)
```

Output: `array([24,  5, 29, 25, 27, 60, 33, 64, 58])`

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish only the get the code, there you go:

np.min(A, axis=(1,2))